# Understanding Promise.all in javascript

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a sample code and questions along with that

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const promiseFunction = (item) => {
    const database = new AWS.DynamoDB();
    const params = {
        TableName: 'some-table',
        Item: item
    }

    try {
        //database.putItem(params).promise(); //3
        //Updated as per the comments..
        return database.putItem(params).promise(); //3
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Error`);
    }
}

const test = async () => {
    const arr = [];
    try {
        for (let data=1;data<=1000;data++) {
            const obj = { data: {N: data.toString()}} 
            arr.push(promiseFunction(obj)); //1
        }
        const result = await Promise.all(arr); //2
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Error`);
    }
}
test();
```

Some follow-up questions:

1. At line-2, the result will contain the resolve/reject result once all the promise based function get executed on line //1. Right?
2. How, the promiseFunction at line-1 is executing and inserting item in dynamodb as I am just pushing it into an array rather than calling the dynamo putItem API. Technically, all 'putItem' should start execute in parallel at line-2. Please help here?
3. Is the above piece of code is valid in terms of Promise.all and executing insert operations in parallel. Please advice.

Comment: `promiseFunction(obj)` *does* call the function, wether or not you push the *result* of that call somewhere, assign it to a variable or ignore it does not matter, you call the function.

Answer (score 2):

> At line-2, the result will contain the resolve/reject result once all the promise based function get executed on line //1. Right?

The `result` will be assigned once all the promises in the `arr` have been fulfilled. `Promise.all` doesn't know (or care) how those promises were created.

> Technically, all 'putItem' should start execute in parallel at line-2.

No. All the `putItem()` calls are executed in your loop. `Promise.all` doesn't execute anything, it only waits for promises created earlier. The request are done concurrently because the code starts them all at once, without waiting in between each loop iteration, not because it uses `Promise.all`.

> Is the above piece of code is valid in terms of `Promise.all` and executing insert operations in parallel.

No. Your `promiseFunction` doesn't actually return a promise, since you forgot a `return` statement on the line marked as `//3`. Once you add that, the code is fine though.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi for the clarification. Also, I don't know why  the question does have -1.